# How to deploy Flask-SocketIO on server?

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I've made a project that using `flask_socketio` extension for user notifications and i want to deploy it on server .

I've already finished reading the `Flask-SocketIO` [documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and just did everything literally in **Deployment section**.

Now if i run the application at the beginning everything works fine, inside the console i've just logged a message if user logged in that says **User Connected!** just to make sure it work .

Now, i am logged in and the site works just fine, but if i want to navigate the other pages of the site it hangouts for a while lets say 30s and it logs me out .

Here is some code snippets:

**base.html** the base is extended for all pages

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/notifications-{{session.get("client_logged_in")}}-{{session.get("client_family")}}');
    var appointments_received = [];
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        console.log('User Connected!');
    });
    socket.on('new_message', function(msgChat){
        $('<li class="notification">\
                <div class="notification_client_ava_border">\
                    {% if '+msgChat.image+' %}\
                        <img src="/static/img/'+msgChat.image+'" alt="myproject" class="notification_client_ava">\
                        {% else %}\
                            <img src="/static/img/main.png" alt="myproject" class="notification_client_ava">\
                    {% endif %}\
                </div>\
                <div class="notification_info">\
                    <div class="client_info">\
                        <p class="user_name">\
                            You have new message from: '+msgChat.from+'\
                            '+shortName+'\
                        </p>\
                    </div>\
                    <br>\
                    <div class="service_info">\
                        {% if '+actionArray[0] == +' "Message:" %}\
                            <span>'+msgChat.message+'</span></br>\
                        {% endif %}\
                    </div>\
                    <br><br>\
                    <div class="">\
                        <span class="date">\
                                '+moment().fromNow()+'\
                        </span>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
                <div class="notification_action">\
                    <a href="/user/cat-{{g.current_directory}}/chat/'+msgChat.to_url_+'?current_user={{session.get("client_logged_in")}}+{{session.get("client_family")}}" id="noty_read" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-get='+msgChat.noty_id+'>read it</a>\
                </div>\
            </li>'
        ).appendTo('ul#messages_list');
    });
</script>
```

**myapp.service** here the Gunicorn instance to serve my project inside system directory

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn
After=network.target

[Service]
User=gard
WorkingDirectory=/home/gard/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/gard/myproject/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/gard/myproject/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 manage:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is also my project **config** file the `Nginx` using to serve my project:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 123.45.678.901;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            break;
        }
    }
    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io;
    }
}
```

Here all my codes that i can provide and i repeat , the site work just fine and i can see the **User Connected!** message inside the console when user logs in my home page , but if i want to navigate another pages the hangs happens and it logs me out of site .

I forgot to show the error that i indeed up with inside the console :

`http://123.45.678.901/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LtFziAg&sid=636e939b538f4b0ca6df5cd521c2e187 400 (BAD REQUEST)`

Comment: You said you followed the deployment instructions in the documentation, but the gunicorn startup command you are using does not use eventlet or gevent as explained in the docs. You can't use a regular gunicorn worker for this, you have to use an async framework. Both eventlet and gevent are supported by gunicorn.

Comment: Sir, i tried to run it with eventlet, but i am getting an error says :
`from eventlet.support import greenlets as greenlet, clear_sys_exc_info, monotonic, six
File "/home/gard/ubook/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/monotonic.py", line 167, in <module>
raise RuntimeError('no suitable implementation for this system')
RuntimeError: no suitable implementation for this system`

Comment: Also i tried gevent but the same problem it hangs for a while and then it logged me out with two error this time :
`socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LtQ_px8&sid=39649bc8aaaf48de9ae223775f90671d 502 (Bad Gateway)`
`socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LtQ_v-A&sid=39649bc8aaaf48de9ae223775f90671d 400 (BAD REQUEST)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved , i must define which async_mode to use inside the `SocketIO` structure .

`Flask-SocketIO` by default gives the first choice for `Eventlet` , the second choice goes to `Gevent` , for more information read this [issues/294](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/294)

To resolve this kind of problem just add this to your code :

socketio = SocketIO(async_mode='gevent')

Comment: This is okay, but in general it is not necessary to specify the async mode explicitly. The async mode is determined automatically from what you have installed in your virtual environment. If all you have gevent installed (and not eventlet), then that is the mode that will be used.

Comment: Am afraid to say sir that i've installed both of them :), maybe that what caused the problem, and the app doesn't know which one to use , the startup command using gevent and socketio using eventlet as default mode, i am not sure !!!

Comment: Sure, but do you really need both? If you are using gevent, why have eventlet installed as well? Uninstall eventlet and that removes the need to set the async mode explicitly.

Comment: Thank you sir for your interest , learned a lot from you especially The Flask Mega-Tutorial , always the best :) .

Comment: @Miguel How can i check in which mode flask socket io is working?

Comment: @Himanshu it is shown in the logs when the server starts up.